# can't get data from await/async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, gtmetrix

I'm trying out the gtmetriks api with nodejs.
i've an index.js file where i handle incoming requests,
then i've a gtmetriks.js file to make requests to the api.

The problem is that i don't know how to configure it to get the data in index.js only after gtmetriks.js has finished the request and got the data.

index.js:

```
const gtmetriks = require('../gtmetrix/gtmetrix');

router.get('/api/gtmetriks', (req, res) => {
        const result = gtmetriks()
        console.log(result);  
        res.send(result);    
    })
```

gtmetrriks.js:

```
const api = async () => {
console.log('starting');

// Run test from London with Google Chrome
const testDetails = {
    url: 'http://google.com/',
    location: 2,
    browser: 3
};
const test = await gtmetrix.test.create(testDetails);
console.log('test: ', test);

const data = await gtmetrix.test.get(test.test_id, 5000);
console.log('data: ', data);

return data    
}

module.exports = api;
```

The result in the browser is {}.
I assume that this is the value of 'result' because this is the value it gets when it gets initialised.

What am i supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `api` function is `async` and therefore returns a `Promise` that you need to await in your route handler :)

Try

```
router.get('/api/gtmetriks', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await gtmetriks()
    console.log(result);  
    res.send(result);    
})
```

Answer (score 2):

As i can see you declare const api as a `async` function so when you call any `async` function write `await` if front of that function. So it will wait until function resolved all promises and gets the result.

```
router.get('/api/gtmetriks', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await gtmetriks()
    console.log(result);  
    res.send(result);    
})
```